# Convert a struct to a byte[] or void[] in D

Tags: data-structures, d

Is there any quick and easy method of converting a struct to a byte array in D? I'm not really finding anything in the D docs.

Comment: I don't know D, but I'm curious, what's `void[]`?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: In D, `T[]` is a slice, which can be thought as `struct { T* ptr; size_t length; }`. So `void[]` is a slice of some arbitrary data like `void*` in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void[] arr;
MyStruct s;
arr = (&s)[0..1];
```

Dynamic arrays of all types (constness still applies) implicitly convert to `void[]`.

Answer (score 2):

This builds for me:

```
struct Foo
{
    int x;
}

void main()
{
    Foo foo;
    auto bytes = *(cast(byte[Foo.sizeof]*)(&foo));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
auto byteArray = (cast(ubyte*) &myStruct)[0 .. myStruct.sizeof];
```

or to use union

```
union MyUnion {
    MyStruct myStruct;
    ubyte[MyStruct.sizeof] byteArray;
}
```